# Javascript filter array by multiple columns

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that I fetch from a yacht booking world wide api.

The object contains data such as price, berths, cabins, equipments on board, number of WC, etc.

I have another big object that holds the filters that are set

```
if (filters.berths.length > 0)
```

And then I have to do the filter, this means that there is a berths filter on, I do for each on the berths filter, each node iterated holds the value of how many berths.

For example if there are 2 and 4 in the berths filter, we will only show books that has either 2 or 4 berths.

But then again, we add more and more different filters and it should be AND and not OR.

How can I do that, is there an algorithm for this?

Comment: Use `array.every()` across all the filters, and `array.any()` to match each filter against the item.

Comment: Please show us how the array of objects looks like and how the result should look like.

Comment: `every()` implements `AND`, while `any()` implements `OR`.

Comment: You can also use `array.includes()` to test the item against the filter.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution - chained Array#filter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

If you need something more advanced, you may search for a "model imitating" library, like: https://github.com/bvaughn/js-search or http://benpickles.github.io/js-model/